# Remoting to Bonobo Git Server on IIS Network

Tags: git, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, bonobo

To whatever jackass who downvoted my legitimate question, the answer is here:

[Running a Git Server on Windows Server 2012 R2/IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076074/running-a-git-server-on-windows-server-2012-r2-iis)

---Original Question---

We have two virtual machines running on the local network.  For the sake of this question let's say the IP of the first machine is 11.11.11.11 and the second machine 22.22.22.22.  They are both running Windows Server 2012 R2/IIS 8. 11.11.11.11 is running Bonobo Git Server, and everything appears to be working fine.

I am attempting to clone a repository "TestRepo" from 11.11.11.11 using machine 22.22.22.22.  I've followed [the directions on the Bonobo Git Server site](https://bonobogitserver.com/frequently-asked-questions/) to do so in a number of different forms.  None of them work.  The URL of "TestRepo" in Bonobo on the 11.11.11.11 machine is http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git

These are the attempts and the error messages that were tossed back to me:

```
 git clone http://11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git
 fatal repository 'http://11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git' not found

 git clone http://WindowsUser@11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git
 fatal repository '11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git' not found

 git clone http://WindowsUser:WindowsPassword@11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git
 fatal repository '11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git' not found

 git clone http://admin@11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git
 fatal repository '11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git' not found

 git clone http://admin:admin@11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git
 fatal repository '11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git' not found
```

and similar variations without the http:

```
 git clone 11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git
 fatal repository '11.11.11.11/Bonobo.Git.Server/TestRepo.git' does not exist
```

I've checked the permissions of the App_Data folder and they are set correctly.  Everything else appears fine.

If anyone has any answers, leads or experience with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: Closing this question as duplicate seems wrong at the moment, however you could modify the referenced question to provide the core of the details given here and subsequently close this question yourself.